# Eclipse Dali JPA error : 'Console configuration "" does not exist'

Tags: eclipse, jpa, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, dali

I have looked everywhere and tried to get to the root of this error but am Having no luck.  I have Eclipse STS with Dali JPA Tools installed.  I have a project with a connected HSQLDB and entities.  When I go to the JPA perspective I have this error in my error console :

`Console configuration "" does not exist.`

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I also had this problem once. Arises when you check-out a project from a source control repository and some of the configurations held by the project creator are not shared among team members. By chance, are you using HibernateJPA as the JPA implementation? In that case, check the following:

Go to your project `Properties > Hibernate Settings`, once there, check the combobox below the  *"Default Hibernate Console Configuration"* label and select a console configuration. If none console configuration exists, go to `Run > Run Configurations ...` and under `Hibernate Console Configuration` create a new Configuration, specify the project name, in the "Database connection:" combobox select "[JPA Project Configured Connection]", click Apply and return to the "Hibernate Settings" settings page of your project configuration.

[image: Select a console configuration in your Hibernate settings]

[image]

Once everything is done, clean your project (maybe it has be done a couple of times before the error dissapears though, due to some eclipse issues), if the project doesn't refresh properly, restart Eclipse (yes, it's kind of extreme but sometimes it just works).

If you're using Maven and the m2e plugin, right-click in your project and goto to `Maven > Update Project Configuration...` and wait for the project to been refreshed. 
[image]

Comment: Lol.  That worked!   Not sure how you got that from that extremely helpful error message but thank you for sharing.  Was driving me crazy! :)

Comment: Actually, in Eclipse Luna it is enough to right-click on the project and select Validate to get rid of old JPA errors. There is no need to refresh, clean or maven-update project.

Comment: Sorry @Dustin, I know is a little late now but "you're welcome". I forgot to answer you, my bad. Indeed, I remember this error toke a lot of time and hair to fix, glad it help you in that moment.

Comment: Thanks @mkalkov, glad to know that Eclipse keeps improving! Sadly I'm stuck with Kepler by now

Comment: Just want to say this was caused by an overeager validator and if you use latest JBoss Tools or Developer Studio you should not get it anymore as an error.

Answer (score 2):

In case the Hibernate Console Configuration ist not shown, disable the Hibernate Support for the project and re-enable again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if there is no console configuration with the name of your project, and disabling and re-enabling hibernate support doesn't cause one to appear, you have to create one. This can be done with `Run->Run Configurations`. However, if you get the error that "console configuration [name] already exists" when you try to create a new hibernate console configuration with the same name as your project, it might be because you have a `Java Application` run configuration with that name. In that case, you need to delete the `Java Application` run configuration first, then you can create the `Hibernate` run configuration.